# Event handler for objects of the same Pane

Tags: events, javafx

i'm studying the mechanism of the event handler on javaFX ,but i'm not sure that i have understand it , in Fact I have a little doubt :
if i have two object , they have all necessary code to handle the event (EventHandler interface ecc..),that they BELONG at the SAME stackPane ,the question is : is there a way for the 1st object to launch an event (ActionEvent for example ) that will be handled by the 2 object though they belong at the same Pane?
Because for what i have understand about the "event route",this is not possible ,at least directly.
In essence my little program have a splitpane that divided in two stackpane the screen,in the left panel i have put a gridpane with the button, each of them have the function that permit to draw a different shape ,in the right panel with a canvas.

My idea it was to launch an ActionEvent in setonaction of each button ,implements the EventHandlers on canvas to capture the event 
with relative handle method ,and in the corp of he handle mode discriminate which button is Clicked for drawing the correct shape.
Can someone help me ? Thanks a lot anyway

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Deen! It is actually quite common for different javafx controls to affect each other. This is possible so long as they are in the same scope. Could you clarify how you are creating your buttons and event handlers? Are you using FXML at all or is this purely in java?

Comment: Also, this question needs a little help to be less of a wall of text. Can you tell us what you want to do, what you have tried, including a [mcve], and what results you get?

Comment: ok,at first thanks for the answer , i'll try to explain with some little code that i wrote

Answer (score 0):

```
            package es1;

            import javafx.application.Application;
            import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
            import javafx.event.Event;
            import javafx.event.EventHandler;
            import javafx.scene.Scene;
            import javafx.scene.control.Button;
            import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane;
            import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
            import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
            import javafx.stage.Stage;

    /**
     *
     * @author DAVIDE
     */
         public class Es1 extends Application {

                @Override
                public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
                Button btn = new Button();
                btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
                btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    System.out.println("Hello World!");
                    lanciaevento(this.getClass().toString());

                }
            });

            //add a button on left panel and a textfiled on the right for test if the event launched
            //on the click of the button is reached by the textfield 
            Textfield text = new Textfield();
            StackPane panel1 = new StackPane();
            panel1.getChildren().addAll(btn);
            StackPane panel2 = new StackPane();
            panel2.getChildren().addAll(text);

            splitpane divisore = new splitpane();
            divisore.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, divisore);
            divisore.getItems().addAll(panel1,panel2);


            Scene scene = new Scene(divisore, 600, 450);

            primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();

        }


        public void lanciaevento(String oggetto)
        {
            ActionEvent evento    = new ActionEvent();
        }

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }


       }
```

---

```
            package es1;

            import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
            import javafx.event.EventHandler;
            import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane;

            /**
             *
             * @author DAVIDE
             */
            public class splitpane extends SplitPane implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>{

                private String message_event;



                public String get_message()
                {
                 return(message_event);
                }

                public void set_message(String messaggio)
                {
                 message_event = messaggio;   

                }

                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                            System.out.println("mi ha mandato un messaggio "+event.getSource().toString());

                }



            }
```

---

```
             /*
     * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.

package es1;

   import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
   javafx.event.EventHandler;
   import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

/**
 *
 * @author DAVIDE
 */
public class Textfield extends TextField implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {


    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        this.appendText(event.getSource().toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: suppose that the button is my ideal gridpane with some button ,and the textfield is my canvas where i wanna draw some shape on the base of the button pressed, in essence i wanna launch an event from the pression of the button (setona action)and then handle it on textfield (the same thing i wanna do in my application : press a button of the relative shape for drawing it.